# A Tabhost FragmentActivity to be embedded inside an anctivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an activity with simple buttons(i cannot make this a fragment as it already extends a parent Activity) and a fragment activity which is a tab host. Is it possible for the two of them share the screen space of the view layout.:
The activity layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/select"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

  <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/control_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>


 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="center">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/addto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
   <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/addtoCheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
  </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

The FragmentActivity is a Tab host that has 4 tabs and layout looks like this:

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/coffee"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible for the activity at the end of its height to show the fragmentActivity for the remaining height of the parent layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the activity is the logical container for everything on the screen. i think you are asking if you can have part of the screen used by activity 1, and another part of the screen for use by activity 2.

no, that's not possible.

Comment: activity 1 is a android.app.Activity class while the 2nd is a FragmentActivity, Does this help? PagerView needs a FragmentActivity and my Activity1 is not a FragmentActivity